# Debug in IDz not started

Tags: debugging, postman

I set my debug profile up in the CICS window - as shown - and I start the transaction in postman - I can see the transaction is taken some more time(look like it is waiting for the debugger to start in IDz) - but the debug perspective never get started.
Yes I have enabled the UI daemon is listning on port; 8001

Question: Why is my debug not starting..

[image]

I tried to run the transaction in postman and expected that my debug window starting in iDz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have Windows firewall blocking the connection? Was the program compiled with the TEST param?

Comment: I'll need to check for the firewall - Yes the program is compiled with debug option. Thanks

Comment: Yes you r right Kenny. It was a firewall issue - thanks - Now it's working :-)